# calling class object from other class Not using "global" php

Tags: php, function, class, object, global

I am new to php so please excuse my lack of knowledge. I am using eclipse and have a project with 3 files inside the project. I am creating a find discount class which takes the class object to call a function from another class.  The error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: GetInfoClass line ..
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function getAge() on a non-object line ...

I tried to read about it but I cant seem to understand it. Please help. Thanks

formResponse:

```
    include "GetInfo.php";
    include "IfDiscount.php";
    $IfDiscount= new IfDiscount();
    echo $IfDiscount->findDiscount();
```

class IfDiscount:

```
    class IfDiscount
    { 
    public function findDiscount(){
    $Age = $GetInfoClass->getAge();
        echo $Age;}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$GetInfoClass` is not available to `findDiscount()` because it is out of scope. You should pass it to `findDiscount()` as a parameter to make it available to that method:

```
public function findDiscount($GetInfoClass){
    $Age = $GetInfoClass->getAge();
    return $Age;
}

echo $IfDiscount->findDiscount($GetInfoClass);
```

(You also want to *return* `$Age`, not echo it. You already explicitly echo it when you call that method.)